# Unwanted backslash on parameter while using RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

URL Examples:

```
1) mydomain.com/coding/mysql/
2) mydomain.com/coding/mysql/?contactId=333&UTM=aff
3) mydomain.com/coding/?contactId=333
```

This is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?book=$1&chapter=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?book=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So I print_r($_REQUEST) on the index.php file to see what I was getting:

```
1) Array ( [book] => coding [chapter] => mysql/ )
2) Array ( [book] => coding [chapter] => mysql/ [contactId] => 333 [UTM] => aff )
3) Array ( [book] => coding/ [contactId] => 333 [UTM] => aff )
```

My problem is that I don't want the / showing in the last available parameter
It would not add the / if I call the examples above like this:

```
1) mydomain.com/coding/mysql
2) mydomain.com/coding/mysql?contactId=333&UTM=aff
3) mydomain.com/coding?contactId=333
```

What do I need to change on my rules to have `mydomain.com/coding/mysql?contactId=333&UTM=aff` resulting in `Array ( [book] => coding [chapter] => mysql [contactId] => 333 [UTM] => aff )`

Thanks! Much appreciated. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?book=$1&chapter=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?book=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

Regex is greedy by default, so in the case of `(.+)/?`, the capturing group will consume the *optional* `/` that follows.

You could make the quantifier non-greedy (ie. lazy) like this: `(.+?)/?` or match "anything except a slash" (ie. `[^/]+`) instead of just "anything" (ie. `.+`).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?book=$1&chapter=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?book=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE:** The first rule is simply to prevent a rewrite-loop, since the pattern `^([^/]+)/?$` would also match `index.php` (the rewritten URL-path).

The `NC` flags are not required here since you are matching both lowercase and uppercase *everything* anyway.

---

However, you should be consistent with your trailing slashes and either include a trailing slash or omit it - you shouldn't really allow both and have both serve the same content. This is potentially a "duplicate content" issue (two URLs serving the same content).

If you want to allow both then *301 redirect* from one to the other.

---

**UPDATE:**

> yeah so I have a file locate at `mydomain.com/library.php` when I try to access it I get this instead of the actual file `Array ( [book] => library.php )`

(*Aside:* If you are only matching/forcing trailing slashes - as mentioned in comments then this wouldn't necessarily be an issue.)

This is because the regex above is rather generic. It matches `/<any-path-segment>`. If your URLs (that you want to rewrite) don't contain a dot then you could simply exclude a dot in the regex to avoid matching "files" that have a file extension (like `.php` or `.js` etc.).

For example, modify the above regex as follows to exclude dots:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?book=$1&chapter=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?book=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will match `foo`, but not `foo.txt` (because it contains a dot).

This also avoids the need to have the first rule that matches `index.php`, since this is naturally excluded by the more specific regex.

Generally, you should be as specific as possible with the regex and only match what is required, to avoid accidentally matching too much.

Comment: YAY! It worked!!! Makes sense, thank you so much @MrWhite

Comment: If it's to force I would use the trailing slashes because that's a more natural way to do it so probably need to use the ```(.+?)/?``` ?

Comment: @scully No. To only match URLs with a trailing slash then simply remove the trailing `?` (optional quantifier). ie. `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$` - now the trailing slash is mandatory. (_Aside:_ `(.+?)/?` is basically the same as `([^/]+)/?` - but they work in different ways. The later is probably more efficient.)

Comment: I understand, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm having an issue with the solution beyond the explained should I open another question or add here?

Comment: @scully Probably another question. Although what is the "issue" - maybe a quick fix?

Comment: yeah so I have a file locate at  ```mydomain.com/library.php``` when I try to access it I get this instead of the actual file ```Array ( [book] => library.php )``` I was able to add another rule on top of the previous two (```RewriteRule ^library library.php [END,QSA]```) but what if I just want to access the straight file instead of using another pretty link for it? What do I need to modify in this case? Thank you!

Comment: That's because the regex is rather generic and is matching pretty much _anything_. (In fact, looking at this again, I'm surprised the first rule is not resulting in a rewrite-loop? I think you must have other directives that is preventing this?) Adding an additional rule for each file you want to access is not very practical. You can usually avoid conflicts like this by just making the regex more specific. I've updated my answer.